# Multiplying functions of many parameters in Python

Tags: python, function

It's pretty obvious what is meant by h(x,y,z) = f(x,y)*g(y,z). I'd like to have a device in Python to do something similar, like:

```
fmul(f1(x,y),f2(y,z)) -> lambda x,y,z: f1(x,y)*f2(y,z)
fmul(f1(x,y),f2(z,y)) -> lambda x,y,z: f1(x,y)*f2(z,y)
```

and so on working universally, depending on parameter names. Of course, it won't work the way it's written in the pseudocode above, because Python will first attempt to evaluate the f1 and f2 calls, and since these would be made with some variable names instead of values, it would raise a NameError. Is there a way to pass those variable names unchanged to the definition of lambda, so that I get a proper function object with a well defined parameter order? I imagine it would be relatively easy to do in a language like Lisp, with macros and symbols, but how to do it in Python? The closest thing I found to a solution would be to use the inspect module to retrieve function parameters, but those are strings, so I would have to compose the lambda expression by concatenating strings and then eval that. Isn't there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Are the parameter name fixed (i.e. always `x`, `y`, and `z`) or can they be anything? Do you always call `f1` with `x` and `y`, just with an unknown ordering of the arguments?

Comment: Ideally, I wouldn't want to rely on parameters' names, instead having some way of telling fmul "make the second argument of f1 equal to the first argument of f2" and so on. Of course that would disqualify the inspect method I mentioned. Also, the number of arguments could be anything, not necessarily 2 in both functions.

Comment: Python the language does not have this level of symbolic manipulation. You might want to take a look at [SymPy](www.sympy.org).

Comment: That's probably a good suggestion. In fact I think SymPy internally does what I suggested above, manipulating strings and then possibly converting them to executable functions with eval(). At least I won't have to write the whole thing myself.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the functions as arguments:

```
def fmul(f1, f2):
    return (lambda x,y,z: f1(x,y)*f2(y,z))
```

Comment: Where are the values coming from when executing `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: @ColinBasnett The lambda

Comment: @ColinBasnett They come from the caller of the function that's returned. `newfun = fmul(somefun, someotherfun)` then `newfun(x, y, z)`.

Comment: Good answer.  In addition to the `lambda`, maybe show the alternate version using `def` to make it more clear?

Comment: That's not the point of the question. The point is how to tell fmul which arguments are the same in both functions passed to it.

Comment: OK, I changed the pseudocode part to make it clearer what I have in mind. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the argument names beforehand (and provided you can redefine `f1` and `f2`), you can do it with the use of keyword arguments without mucking with `inspect`:

```
def f1(x, y, **kwargs):
    return x + y


def f2(z, y, **kwargs):
    return z - y


def fmul(f1, f2):
    return lambda x, y, z: f1(x=x, y=y, z=z) * f2(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```